# How to press enter in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I have a Dockerfile with this line:

`RUN  yes n | /opt/TWS/ibgateway-latest-standalone-linux-x64.sh`

when I build the container and get to this line, the installation is expecting I press enter.

I want to know hoe I can send Enter on this line in Dockerfile without using --yes or yes or -y.

I have looked everywhere and nothing suggested has worked, I think it requires Enter like the actual key ENTER or Return on Macs

Comment: You can send keystrokes to a program using expect, although that's probably overkill. Maybe the shell script could be modified to not require you to press enter?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out by searching for about an hour, it is by using yes ''. as shown below:

```
RUN  yes '' | /opt/TWS/ibgateway-latest-standalone-linux-x64.sh
```